# Turn lowercase letters of a string to uppercase and the inverse

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

```
let message = "heY, WHAt are you dOING?";
let count_changes = 0;
let isLetter = (letter) => {
    if (('a'<=letter && letter >='z') || ('A'<=letter && letter >='Z')) {
        return letter;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

for(let i = 0; i <= message.length; i++) {
    if (isLetter(i) && message[i].toLowerCase()) {
        message[i].toUpperCase();
        count_changes++;
        console.log(message[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    else if (isLetter(i) && message[i].toUpperCase()) {
        message[i].toLowerCase();
        count_changes++;
    }
    else {
        console.error('Bad stirng');
    }
}
```

Hello, I want to use the function isLetter to check the string message every character and when i use isLetter in the for loop to check in the if statement whether i is a Letter or not and also if its Lowercase letter later to when there is a change to Uppercase i increment count_changes++. Again with the second if statement if also i is Letter and in this case Uppercase letter then if change to lowercase letter to increment the count_changes++ so the count_changes to be my final result
thank you

Comment: Pretty sure you wanted to use `message.charAt(i)`? Like `if ( isLetter(message.charAt(i).toLowerCase()) ) {}`. Remember that `i` is just a number that represents **the index** (position) of a character in your string. `isLetter()` should return a boolean also.

Comment: Are you sure `'a'<=letter && letter >='z'` is what you want? Maybe `letter  <= 'z'`? Please learn to use punctuation in sentences, it greatly helps comprehension.

Comment: `message[i].toLowerCase()` doesn't return a boolean but a lowercase string, which will always evaluate to `true`, if used that way. The same goes for `message[i].toUpperCase()`.

Comment: `message[i].toUpperCase();` will return that character converted to uppercase, but it will not store that uppercase value back into the string, which is what I think you're imagining will happen.

Comment: the exercise i want to solve is to check the message variable "heY, WHAt are you dOING?";how many times the letter is changed from lower to upper and opposite. First i thought to make a function since there are white spaces , question symbol and in different tests many other symbols. So in the if statement to check if the loop have found a letter from a function and what is that letter upper or lower case, then if it changes to increment the counter

Comment: well, address the myriad of issues pointed out above. re-iterating what you want after being told your code is full of errors wont fix the errors

Comment: My understanding is that you want to count how many times the case changed from upper to lower and back again - without altering the original string value. If so, see my answer below that should accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to count the number of characters in the string and return a string where all uppercase characters are replaced with lowercase characters and all lowercase characters are replaced with uppercase characters. Additionally, you want to increment countChanges once for every character changed.

This code should do what you want:

```
let message = "heY, WHAt are you dOING?";
let countChanges = 0;
let isLetter = c => c.toLowerCase() !== c.toUpperCase();
let isLowerCase = c => c.toLowerCase() === c;

let flippedMessage = Array.from(message).map((c)=>{
    if(!isLetter(c)){
        return c;
    }
    countChanges++;
    // return uppercase character if c is a lowercase char
    if(isLowerCase(c)){
        return c.toUpperCase();
    }
    // Here, we know c is an uppercase character, so return the lowercase
    return c.toLowerCase();
}).join('');

// flippedMessage is "HEy, whaT ARE YOU Doing?"
// countChanges is 18
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You will always have a count of how many letters are in the string - not how many times it changed from upper to lower and vice versa. Also, there was no mention of altering the case to the opposite and returning the flipped version. If I've got this wrong, let me know :)

Comment: @StevePadmore Yes, I am counting the number of letters in the string, (excluding spaces and special characters) with countChanges. But I think that that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I asked because I noticed that all of the other answers were flipping the characters too, but I don't see that requirement in the OP's question. As in 'and also if its Lowercase letter later to when there is a change to Uppercase i increment count_changes++':)

Comment: @StevePadmore Fair enough, the way the question was asked was a little open to interpretation :P

Comment: I was going to edit it, but the question description conflicts with the title. I think 'Turn Lowercase letters...' should have been 'Check Lowercase letters...'. But if the OP is happy...

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

```js
let message = "heY, WHAt are you dOING?";
let newMessage = "";
let count_changes = 0;
let isLowerCaseLetter = (letter) => 'a' <= letter && letter <= 'z';
let isUpperCaseLetter = (letter) => 'A' <= letter && letter <= 'Z';

/* Iterate over every character of the message. */
for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
  /* Cache the character at the current index. */
  let character = message[i];

  /* Check whether the character is a lowercase letter. */
  if (isLowerCaseLetter(character)) {
    newMessage += character.toUpperCase();
    count_changes++;
  }

  /* Check whether the character is an uppercase letter. */
  else if (isUpperCaseLetter(character)) {
    newMessage += character.toLowerCase();
    count_changes++;
  }
  
  /* Otherwise, just add the current character to the new message. */
  else newMessage += character;
}

console.log("New Message: ", newMessage);
console.log("Changes: ", count_changes);
```

---

**Your Mistakes:**

1. The way you're checking if a character is a letter is wrong, due to `>='z'`. It should be `<='z'`. The same goes for the check against `'Z'`.
2. Functions that have a Boolean connotation had better return `true` or `false` instead of `-1` or the character itself as you do.
3. Inside `isLetter` you pass the index instead of the character itself. The function call should be `isLetter(message[i])` instead of `isLetter(i)`.
4. The very message you are testing will be deemed a *'bad string'*, because of the comma and the spaces between the words.
5. In your loop, the condition should be `i < message.length`, otherwise, every message will be deemed a *'bad string'*, because you'll exceed all characters and get an `undefined` value.
6. The methods `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` do not affect the original string but create a new one instead. If you want to assemble the resulting characters together, you have to initialise a `newMessage` string and concatenate it the processed character each loop.

**Suggested solution:**

1. Instead of one `isLetter` function create one checking if a character is a lowercase letter and one checking if it's an uppercase letter. That way you combine your checks and your `if` clause will be much simpler and more readable.
2. Ditch the `isLetter` check and the good string / bad string thing completely, so as not to have problems with in-between characters such as spaces and punctuation.
3. Attempt to minimise function calls, as for large strings, they will slow down your code a lot. In the code below, only **2 function calls per loop** are used, compared to the accepted answer, which makes:

   - 3 function calls per loop plus,
   - 3 function calls when a character is letter *(the majority of the time)*
   - 3 one-time function calls for `from`, `map` and `join`, which will matter for large strings.

**Speedtest:**

In a series of 5 tests using a massive string (2,825,856 chars long) the answers stack up as follows:

- this answer *([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqbkf9vb/34/) used)*:
  `[1141.91ms, 1150.93ms, 1093.75ms, 1048.50ms, 1183.03ms]`
- accepted answer *([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqbkf9vb/35/) used)*:
  `[2211.30ms, 2985.22ms, 2136.73ms, 2279.26ms, 2482.34ms]`

Comment: Is using forEach really that much worse than using traditional for loops? Making n constant-time function calls on a string of this length won't have too much of a performance impact and I prefer the readability of the forEach loop over the for loop.

Comment: Also, regarding point 3, your code makes 2 function calls **inside a loop**, so it is inaccurate for you to say that only 2 function calls are used in your own code. You make 2 function calls __per iteration of the loop__. Also, how did you count 9 function calls in my suggested solution?

Comment: First, you are not using `forEach` in your code. Second, the OP never mentioned how long the strings used will be; I assume the current one is just a placeholder.

Comment: Third, it is a known fact that too many function calls result in slower code. Just count the number of function calls your code makes. You call `isLetter` once per loop which in turn calls `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase`; that's **3 per loop**. Then, the majority of the time, characters will be letters, so `isLowerCase` will be called, which calls `toLowerCase`. Also, based on the check either `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` will be called; that's **3** more, say in **80%** of all loops. For large strings, calling `from`, `map` and `join` also have their toll in computation time.

Comment: Finally, my code makes just **2 function calls per loop**; you are right, I should express it better. Regarding your answer, 9 is a result of summing the aforementioned calls, which admittedly was lousy and I corrected it. Also, at least for me, your code is much less readable than mine, so that point is invalid @keithlee96.

Comment: Actually, for very large strings, my code will be significantly faster than yours, because it's O(n) time complexity, while your solution is O(n^2) time complexity. Though for shorter strings, your code is faster than mine, since the constant factor for overhead is smaller.

Comment: How did you figure out that my answer is **O(n^2)**? Also, how large strings are you referring to? In my speedtest, I used a massive **~3 million chars long** string and your solution is at least twice as slow.

Answer (score 1):

By default, javascript's comparison of strings is case sensitive, therefore you can check a character's case by comparing it to either an upper or lower case converted value.

If it is the same, then the case is what you checked against, if not, the case is different.

`"TRY" == "TrY"` would return `false`, whereas `"TRY" == "TRY"` would return `true`;

So, use a variable to indicate the case of the last letter checked, then compare the next letter to the opposite case. If it matches, the case has changed, otherwise it is still the same case.

The `isLetter` function checks a value to be a single character, and using a regex test ensures that it is a letter - no punctuation or digits etc.

Your loop would always produce an error because you were iterating outside the lenth of the message string - arrays are 0 based.

```
let message = "heY, WHAt are you dOING?";
let count_changes = 0;
let lowerCase = message[0] == message[0].toLowerCase();
let messageLength = message.length;

function isLetter (val) {
    // Check val is a letter of the alphabet a - z ignoring case.
    return val.length == 1 && val.match(/[a-z]/i);
}

for (let i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
    var char = message[i];
    if (isLetter(char)) {
        if(lowerCase) {
            // Check to see if the next letter is upper case when the last one was lower case.
            if(char == char.toUpperCase()) {
                lowerCase = false;
                count_changes++;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Check to see if the next letter is lower case when the last one was upper case.
            if(char == char.toLowerCase()) {
                lowerCase = true;
                count_changes++;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Found a non-letter character.
        console.error('Not a letter.');
    }
}

console.log("Number of times the case changed: " + count_changes);
```